# unable to see shared folder on fedora17 running on Vmware

Tags: fedora, vmware-workstation, shared-directory

I have enabled folder sharing option on VMWARE by enabling VM->settings->options->shared folder option. However I am unable to see the shared folder under /mnt or /media. Can some one please suggest me the steps to follow to enable this option.

Comment: Is Fedora your guest or your host? Or both? Do you have the option of updating to current, supported Fedora? Fedora 17 reached end of life in July, 2013, and no longer receives updates for security or bugfixes.

Comment: Fedora 17 is years after EOL. Please update to something more recent.

Comment: I am using Windows7 as Host OS and fedora17 as guest. I will try to update to current fedora available. thanks @mattdm and jakuje

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `open-vm-tools` installed on your Fedora guest. From the changelog, it looks like this was initially added right *after* Fedora 17. In any case, you almost certainly want a newer version than the one that was in that Fedora release (which has not gotten updates since July 2013). Fortunately, you can do this by installing a newer Fedora release. I *bet* everything will Just Work™.